How to add a logout button to Swagger UI in Springdoc OpenAPI?
I am using Springdoc OpenAPI with the following configuration in

application.yml

springdoc:
  version: '@springdoc.version@'
  cache:
    disabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
  api-docs:
    version: openapi_3_1

I have also added the OpenAPI 3 dependency like this

pom.xml

<!-- OpenAPI 3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>

Now, I want to add a logout button to the Swagger UI. When the user clicks this button, it should call the URL {baseUrl}/logout.
Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this in Swagger UI? Thank you in advance!
